# How to clear webrequestsession sessions created using sessionvariable parameter in Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I need to clear the sessions created using Invoke-RestMethod.

Sessions stored in ws variable in below line.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $page -Body $Params -sessionvariable ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a powershell variable have you tried using this command?

```
Remove-Variable ws
```

I tried this with Invoke-Webrequest in the past, and had no issues with it.

Comment: Not sure if it is going to clear the session from server.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you call a web session, the target holds that session for a predefined length of time.

You have to exit the session forcibly if you want to drop it. No different the closing and restarting your web browser after visiting a site. You can try and use the -Timeout param as part of your call.

[Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)

> ***[-TimeoutSec ]***
>
> Specifies how long the request can be pending before it times out. Enter a value in seconds. The default value, 0, specifies
>   an indefinite time-out. A Domain Name System (DNS) query can take up
>   to 15 seconds to return or time out. If your request contains a host
>   name that requires resolution, and you set -TimeoutSec to a value
>   greater than zero, but less than 15 seconds, it can take 15 seconds or
>   more before a WebException is thrown, and your request times out.

and / or

***[-MaximumRetryCount ]***

> Specifies how many times PowerShell retries a connection when a
>   failure code between 400 and 599, inclusive or 304 is received. Also
>   see -RetryIntervalSec parameter for specifying number of retries.

So, if you did this as a job, then the session should drop after the job finishes. Yet, doing a manual garbage collection, may be prudent as well. Here snippet I have in my library that I use for cleanups. Which fires just before my app / script / process exits.

```
Function Clear-ResourceEnvironment
{
    # Clear any PowerShell sessions created
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

    # Release an COM object created
    $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$Shell)

    # Perform garbage collection on session resources 
    [System.GC]::Collect()         
    [GC]::Collect()
    [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    # Remove any custom varialbes created
    Get-Variable -Name MyShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Variable
}
```

You could also just be getting a TCP connection hang in Close_Wait what using Put / Delete with Invoke-RestMethod.